# Spark Streaming input rate drop

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Running a Spark Streaming job, I have encountered the following behavior more than once. Processing starts well: the processing time for each batch is well below the batch interval. Then suddenly, the input rate drops to near zero. [See these graphs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ovid.png)

This happens even though the program could keep up and it slows down execution considerably. I believe the drop happens when there is not much unprocessed data left, but because the rate is so low, these final records take up most of the time needed to run the job. Is there any way to avoid this and speed up?

I am using PySpark with `Spark 1.6.2` and using the **direct approach for Kafka** streaming. `Backpressure` is turned on and there is a `maxRatePerPartition` of 100.

Comment: Is `spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled` enabled?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, it is.

Comment: Disable it, it's a byproduct of it thinking the pressure is bigger than your system can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Setting backpressure is more meaningful in the case of old spark streaming versions where you need receivers to consume the messages from a stream. From Spark 1.3 you have the receiver-less “direct” approach to ensure stronger end-to-end guarantees. So you do not need to worry about backpressure as spark does most of the fine tuning.